# iPad: add fullscreen-image during applicationDidFinishLaunching depending on orientation

Tags: ipad, orientation, uiwindow

I'd like to make a "splash screen" while starting the iPad app: the Default-[Landscape|Portrait]~ipad.png is shown while starting, afterwards I'd like to add the same image by myself and let it fade out.

The problem is the orientation during applicationDidFinishLaunching; I've got problems to determine to correct image and add it to UIWindow (which seems to be in portrait).

How's it possible to add a fullscreen-image during launch and then let it fade out?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that it is considered bad practice, and actively discouraged by Apple, as stated in the UI Guidelines, to use a "splashscreen". You're supposed to show either a screenshot of the last state or a picture of the most probable state of the application, to give a sense of loading speed and reduce user anxiety, and then immediately move into "active mode".

Answer (score 2):

You can add `flashView` to your `RootViewController.view` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
flashView = [...]; // save reference to this object
flashView.alpha = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:flashView];
```

And after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` animate alpha property to 0.0 in `RootViewController`'s `viewDidAppear`:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = 1.0;
int curve = UIViewAnimationCurveLinear;

 // Setup the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"splash fade out" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// change alpha
flashView.alpha = 0.0;

// Commit the changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: yes, but how to get the orientation in viewDidLoad? Both, the device and self.interfaceOrientation tell me that I'm starting in landscape, which is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with orientation during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is expected behavior; see [Get launch orientation of iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402401/get-launch-orientation-of-ipad-app/5533222#5533222) for a previous question on exactly this topic.

The best solution is to have your root view controller handle displaying the splash screen, or present the splash screen using a modal view controller with `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`. That way you can react to the normal [view rotation events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW58) and change the splash screen image as needed.

Or you may be able to read UIDevice's [`orientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW3) property, but it is certainly possible that this too won't be updated (even if you call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) until too late.

Comment: but I don't manage it to get the correct orientation... it's always telling me that I'm in portrait, although I'm starting in landscape...

Comment: @swalkner: Did you read the linked answer? Apple documents that the orientation will be portrait during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. At some point after that method returns, the normal UIViewController rotation mechanism will be used to rotate your interface to the actual orientation. Which is why I suggest that you display your splash screen from a UIViewController and use the normal view rotation events to adjust your image for the orientation as needed.