# landscape orientation for iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to have landscape orientation for my app.
So I have done the following:
*in `Info.plist` file I've set this:
[image: allt text]

And then in every ViewController.m of my application I've done this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
        return YES;

    else return NO;
}
```

And well this is the result:
[image: allt text]

What should I do for the tabel to look right.Thanks

Comment: refer this link it may be help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369381/detect-iphone-orientation-before-loading-tableview

Comment: I think this can help you:

[iPhone SDK: Orientation (Landscape and Portrait views)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431165/iphone-sdk-orientation-landscape-and-portrait-views

Comment: Nothing works.Tried everything:)

Answer (score 0):

Your looking in the wrong place: in your RootViewController.m file look for the following code:

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
//lots of useless comments
//
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation) ); //THIS LINE HERE
//Change it to say this:
//return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandScape(interfaceOrientation) );
```

the line that says return (UIInterface... Portrait) is the line that determines your app's rotating capabilities. You can change this to whatever to allow you to be able to rotate completely, keep it at a certain orientation, or whatever you desire...