# Not getting proper orientation at the time of Launching application on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am working on iPad application. My problem is I am not getting proper orientation in my first view controller. I have checked `shouldAutorotate` function as well. App gets proper orientation if i move device horizontally or vertically. But I can see springboard is in landscape mode and even Application Splash screen is Landscape but still my first view controller appears in portrait. I am not able to find solution for this. Is any one having idea about this??

I am not able to find the cause of this issue.

And one more issue is I have created my application 1 year ago with xcode 3.2 and now I am using xcode 4.2 now I am facing some interesting message on my console when app starts "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch".
My app is having navigation controller and I am adding it no window.

Any one is having idea about `self.window.rootViewController` property?? How can I solve this warning?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the orientation problem, see this question:

- [Get launch orientation of iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402401/get-launch-orientation-of-ipad-app)

For the Xcode 3 vs Xcode 4 issue with root view controller, that will be that you're not setting the `rootViewController` property of your `UIWindow`. You need to either hook it up in IB or set it in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, probably like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController; ///< Assuming your navigation controller is called `navController'
```